# 8. 0.11 - Installer Error - Authenticatioin Method

Tags: mysql, server, failed-installation

I've encountered difficulties installing the MySQL Server 8.0.11. I've successfully installed Workbench, and it appears to open and operate without any errors, but I was advised to download the server as well.

The install goes smoothly (using all default options) until the "authentication method" options, where there doesn't seem to be any way to make a selection and move on. I can toggle between either method, but I can't actually move past this page.

Has anyone else encountered this? Am I missing a step somewhere, like do I need to do something inside of workbench to prep for the server install?

MySQL Installer 8.0.11 Authentication Method Error:
[image: MySQL Installer 8.0.11 Authentication Method Error]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your operating system is Windows:

1. Click Start. Type Font Size in the search box, and press Enter.
2. In the Display window that appears, choose the Small font size (100 percent of the default size)

3.restart your operating system

Then, the "next" button on  "authentication method" panel will appear.